# Binding values in query TypeOrm

Tags: javascript, sql, typeorm, nest

I am currently designing a chat in nestJS where you can send private messages to other users.

I have a repository Private Messages that hold every messages between two users, on which I build queries, but I would like to bind values in order to make it more readable.

I have this code :

```
    public async getPrivateMessage(sender: string, target: string)
    {
        let user1: User = await this.userService.getUserByIdentifier(sender);
        let user2: User = await this.userService.getUserByIdentifier(target);


        const msgs = this.pmRepo.createQueryBuilder("PM")
            .where(new Brackets(qb => {
                qb.where("PM.sender = :dst", { dst: user1.id })
                .orWhere("PM.sender = :dst1", { dst1: user2.id })
            }))
            .andWhere(new Brackets(qb => {
                qb.where("PM.target = :dst", { dst: user1.id })
                .orWhere("PM.target = :dst1", { dst1: user2.id })
            }))
            .getMany();
        return msgs;
    }
```

...which returns the following JSON :

```js
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "message": "test0 ",
        "sender": "04c40d7b-bf0c-4d7d-a6c1-4ec93f9bb472",
        "target": "617c1640-b0df-448e-8b55-a67131e77456"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "message": "test1 ",
        "sender": "04c40d7b-bf0c-4d7d-a6c1-4ec93f9bb472",
        "target": "617c1640-b0df-448e-8b55-a67131e77456"
    },
```

I would like it to display names instead of IDs, something like

```js
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "message": "test0 ",
        "sender": "name of sender",
        "target": "name of target"
    },
```

...knowing that this data is held by my user1 and user2, objects of class User, in a field "name". I would like to bind the fields sender and target to a name but do not really know where to look for.

[EDIT]

Following answer, I edited the code and tried something like :

```
const msgs = this.pmRepo.createQueryBuilder("PM")
            .leftJoinAndSelect(User, 'user', 'user.id = PM.sender')
            .where(new Brackets(qb => {
                qb.where("PM.sender = :dst", { dst: user1.id })
                    .orWhere("PM.sender = :dst1", { dst1: user2.id })
            }))
            .andWhere(new Brackets(qb => {
                qb.where("PM.target = :dst", { dst: user1.id })
                    .orWhere("PM.target = :dst1", { dst1: user2.id })
            }))
            .getMany();
```

to have at least the sender object.

Unfortunately I still have the same output. Here is the performed SQL query :

```
query: SELECT "PM"."id" AS "PM_id", "PM"."message" AS "PM_message", "PM"."sender" AS "PM_sender", "PM"."target" AS "PM_target", "user"."id" AS "user_id", "user"."name" AS "user_name", "user"."mail" AS "user_mail" FROM "privateMessage" "PM" LEFT JOIN "Users" "user" ON "user"."id" = "PM"."sender" WHERE ("PM"."sender" = $1 OR "PM"."sender" = $2) AND ("PM"."target" = $3 OR "PM"."target" = $4) -- PARAMETERS: ["04c40d7b-bf0c-4d7d-a6c1-4ec93f9bb472","617c1640-b0df-448e-8b55-a67131e77456","04c40d7b-bf0c-4d7d-a6c1-4ec93f9bb472","617c1640-b0df-448e-8b55-a67131e77456"]
```

[EDIT BIS]

Okay, just found out this issue saying that getMany() could be the faulty one : https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/5851
I use getRawMany() instead and I get more data now that will be enough. Still going around a solution with joinAndMap to see what I can achieve.

Solution with getRawMany() :

```
const msgs = this.pmRepo.createQueryBuilder("PM")
            .leftJoinAndSelect("Users", "uSender", "uSender.id = PM.sender")
            .leftJoinAndSelect("Users", "uTarget", "uTarget.id = PM.target")
            .where(new Brackets(qb => {
                qb.where("PM.sender = :dst", { dst: user1.id })
                    .orWhere("PM.sender = :dst1", { dst1: user2.id })
            }))
            .andWhere(new Brackets(qb => {
                qb.where("PM.target = :dst", { dst: user1.id })
                    .orWhere("PM.target = :dst1", { dst1: user2.id })
            }))
            .getRawMany();
```

[FINAL EDIT]

I finally had my final solution. I am not really sure of what I am doing, but still, it gave me exactly what I wanted :

```
        const msgs = this.pmRepo.createQueryBuilder("PM")
            .leftJoinAndMapOne("PM.sender", User, 'users', 'users.id = PM.sender')
            .leftJoinAndMapOne("PM.target", User, 'usert', 'usert.id = PM.target')
            .where(new Brackets(qb => {
                qb.where("PM.sender = :dst", { dst: user1.id })
                    .orWhere("PM.sender = :dst1", { dst1: user2.id })
            }))
            .andWhere(new Brackets(qb => {
                qb.where("PM.target = :dst", { dst: user1.id })
                    .orWhere("PM.target = :dst1", { dst1: user2.id })
            }))
            .getMany();
```

The output :

```
  {
        "id": 2,
        "message": "test",
        "sender": {
            "id": "617c1640-b0df-448e-8b55-a67131e77456",
            "name": "one",
            "mail": "one@lol.fr"
        },
        "target": {
            "id": "04c40d7b-bf0c-4d7d-a6c1-4ec93f9bb472",
            "name": "two",
            "mail": "two@lol.fr"
        }
    }
```

I would like to select only the name but for now it will do the trick ! If anyone has a solution for that, I will still take. Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

You should add left join to users, there are examples in typ
[typeOrm Documentation](https://typeorm.io/select-query-builder#joining-any-entity-or-table)

I am not sure I can tell you exactly for your solution, but something like this:

```
.leftJoinAndSelect("users", "uSender", "uSender.id = PM.sender")
.leftJoinAndSelect("users", "uTarget", "uTarget.id = PM.target")
```

Join twice for both users and after that you should have all data you need, just to format desire output.

Comment: Hi, I tried your solution and following tutorial : https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/master/docs/select-query-builder.md#inner-and-left-joins. It stills does not work, I'll edit the message to make visible the SQL performed query also to maybe figure out what is going on.